# Ricci curvature tensor arguments

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

i do not understand the application of the Weizenböck identity,
$$
\Delta = \nabla^*\nabla + \text{Ric},
$$

where $\Delta = \text{d}\delta+\delta\text{d}$. It is applied like this

$$
\eqalign{
(\text{d}\delta\text{d} u)\cdot \text{d}v &= ((\text{d}\delta+\delta\text{d})\text{d}u)\cdot(\text{d}v) \\
&=(\nabla^*\nabla\text{d}u)\cdot(\text{d}v)+\text{Ric}(\text{d}u,\text{d}v)
}
$$

and i do not understand why the second argument in $\text{Ric}$ is $\text{d}v$ and not $\text{d}u$ since the operator that is exchanged operates on $\text{d}u$. Please correct me :).

Comment: It is just a matter of notations. If $g$ is a metric and if $A$ is a $(1,1)-$tensor, one can define a $(2,0)$-tensor $\tilde{A}$ by $\tilde{A}(X,Y) = g(A(X),Y)$. The map $A \mapsto \tilde{A}$ is an isomorphism (this is the so-called Riesz's representation theorem) , so sometimes, we write them both $A$, and the context gives us which one of them is used. In your notations : $\mathrm{Ric}(\mathrm{d}u,\mathrm{d}v) = (\mathrm{Ric}(\mathrm{d}u))\cdot(\mathrm{d}v)$.

Comment: Thanks for reply :)
But in the reference i am found this they write that Ric is a (0,2) tensor. Also they say that the concrete definition does not matter because on 2 dimensional manifolds the Ricci curvature tensor simplifies to $Ric = kg$ where $k$ is the gaussian curvature and $g$ is the metric.
So all if i know the metric tensor is a (0,2) tensor, did you switch the (2,0) accidentally ?

Comment: I possibily made this mistake. What is important is that in the Weinzenbröck formula, $\mathrm{Ric}$ is the endomorphism while in the last equality, it is the associated bilinear form